# DateTime Format from dd/mm/yyyy format to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: c#

how to convert date from dd/mm/yyyy format to yyyy-mm-dd using C#.net. please advice

Comment: There's **got to be** at least a gazillion duplicates for this - didn't you get any `Questions with similar titles` when you asked this question????

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are looking for this:

```
d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Where `d` above is a DateTime.

Example:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Now;

Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
```

Prints:

```
2011-12-01
01/12/2011
```

Comment: ok. got it, thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Probably the most reliable way to do it is to parse your incoming string representing a date:

```
var date = DateTime.Parse("30/11/2011");
```

then get the string representation of the returned DateTime object:

```
var yyyy_mm_dd = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

yyyy_mm_dd will contain "2011-11-30"

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: Wouldn't the format be "yyyy-MM-dd" as mm is for minutes.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy, take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx). Another way is just to do:

```
DateTime oldDT = DateTime.Parse("Date in old format"); // And then, later:
DateTime newDT = DateTime.Parse(oldDT.ToString("New format string"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

This will be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");`// this will return formatted as string